# JavaScript/jQuery: array random issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to randomize an array with DOM elements, like this:

```
var allTargets=$('#target1, #target2, #target3, #target4');
var randomTargets=null;
randomTargets = allTargets[Math.floor(Math.random() * allTargets.length)];
console.log(randomTargets);
```

In the console I can see the array is shuffled each time I refresh the page. But when I try to trigger a method with the randomTargets variable, the program crashes. Something like this:

```
randomTargets.hide();
```

But without the random variable, the program works:

```
var allTargets=$('#target1, #target2, #target3, #target4');
allTargets.hide();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *In the console I can see the array is shuffled each time I refresh the page."* No, nothing is shuffling that (which is a jQuery object, not an array). You *are* picking a random element from the (unshuffled) jQuery object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you meant this which will not shuffle but just hide a random element based on a random number from 0 to length of allTargets

```
var $allTargets = $('#target1, #target2, #target3, #target4');
var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * allTargets.length);
$allTargets.eq(rnd).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Accessing a jQuery object "like an array" gives you a native DOM element which has no `hide()` method.

From the docs at https://api.jquery.com/get/

> Each jQuery object also masquerades as an array, so we can use the
>   array dereferencing operator to get at the list item instead:
>
> ```
> console.log( $( "li" )[ 0 ] );
> ```

So in your case `$(randomTargets).hide();` will work.

Comment: well, the program crashes still